# Comparar duas strings em C

Tags: c, string

Olá, pessoal, quero comparar duas strings porém o resultado não está retornando o que é esperado, que nesse caso seria o índice na função busca_nome, o erro está na quarta linha da função busca, mas estou disponibilizando todo código. o teste da quarta linha não esta retornando verdadeiro nem quando as duas strings são iguais, alguém sabe me dizer por que? Grato desde já.

```
/* 
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: pmargreff
 *
 * Created on 6 de Novembro de 2014, 00:25
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

struct end {
    char nome[100];
    char rua[100];
    char cidade[100];
    char estado[100];
    unsigned long int cep;
} info[MAX];

/*
 * struct para conseguir comparar 
 * dois nomes em diversas funções
 */
struct compara {
    char nome[100];
} busca;

void cria_lista(void);
void insere(void);
void apaga(void);
void imprime(void);
int menu(void);
int livre(void);
void ler_string(char palavra[100], int tamanho);

int main(void) {
    int escolha;
    cria_lista();
    for (;;) {
        escolha = menu();
        switch (escolha) {
            case 1: insere();
                break;
            case 2: apaga();
                break;
            case 3: imprime();
                break;
            case 4: exit(0);
                break;
        }
    }
}

void cria_lista(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        info[i].nome[0] = '\0';
}

int menu(void) {
    int c = 0;
    do {
        printf("-- MENU:\n");
        printf("\t 1. Inserir um nome\n");
        printf("\t 2. Excluir um nome\n");
        printf("\t 3. Listar o arquivo\n");
        printf("\t 4. Sair\n");
        printf("-- Digite sua escolha: ");
        scanf("%d", &c);
    } while (c <= 0 || c > 4);
    getchar();
    return c;
}

void ler_string(char palavra[100], int tamanho) {
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    c = getchar();
    while ((c != '\n') && (i < tamanho)) {
        palavra[i++] = c;
        c = getchar();
    }
    palavra[i] = '\0';
    if (c != '\n') {
        c = getchar();
        while ((c != '\n') && (c != EOF)) {
            c = getchar();
        }
    }
}

void insere(void) {
    int posicao;
    posicao = livre();
    if (posicao == -1) {
        printf("\nEstrutura Cheia!!");
        return;
    }
    printf("-- Registro %d:\n", posicao);
    printf("\t Nome: ");
    ler_string(info[posicao].nome, 30);
    printf("\t Rua: ");
    ler_string(info[posicao].rua, 40);
    printf("\t Cidade: ");
    ler_string(info[posicao].cidade, 20);
    printf("\t Estado: ");
    ler_string(info[posicao].estado, 2);
    printf("\t CEP: ");
    scanf("%lu", &info[posicao].cep);
}

int livre(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; info[i].nome[0] && i < MAX; i++);
    if (i == MAX) return -1;
    return i;
}

/*
 * chama a funçao busca_nome que retorna o indice
 * para a variavel posicão que devera ser apagado
 * se nenhum nome igual for encontrado retorna -1
 */
void apaga(void) {
    int posicao;
    posicao = busca_nome();
    if (posicao >= 0 && posicao < MAX)
        info[posicao].nome[0] = '\0';
}

void imprime(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        if (info[i].nome[0] != '\0') {
            printf("-- Registro %d:\n", i);
            printf("\t Nome: %s", info[i].nome);
            printf("\t Rua: %s", info[i].rua);
            printf("\t Cidade: %s", info[i].cidade);
            printf("\t Estado: %s\n", info[i].estado);
            printf("\t CEP: %lu\n", info[i].cep);
        }
}

/*
 * função que faz a busca de um nome no programa
 * le o nome que está localizado na struct busca.nome
 * e retorna o indice se encontrar nome igual ou
 * -1 se não encontrar nome como aquele
 */
int busca_nome(void) {
    int i;
    ler_string(busca.nome, 30);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        if (info[i].nome == busca.nome){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: `"mas estou disponibilizando todo código"` Isso não é recomendável. O ideal é [reduzir o código postado para conter apenas o que for relevante ao problema](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Se você reduzir o código na sua pergunta as chances de você conseguir uma boa resposta aumentam.

Comment: para comparar strings em c voce precisa usar a funcao strcmp. nao existe o operador== para vetores.

Comment: Seguirei as dicas, valeu.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

O seu problema esta na comparação:

```
    if (info[i].nome == busca.nome){
        return i;
    }
```

Na realidade esta a comparar os ponteiros e não o conteúdo dos vectores, dai o facto de que mesmo `strings` iguais davam falso na comparação.

Utilize antes [`strcmp`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strcmp.htm) para realizar a comparação:

```
#include <string.h> 

...

if (strcmp(info[i].nome, busca.nome) == 0){
    return i;
}
```

---

**Extra**

(Nota: prefira utilizar `strcmp` mas do ponto de vista de aprendizagem):

Pode implementar a sua própria comparação utilizando o seguinte código:

```
int index = 0;
// Enquanto os caracteres forem iguais, corre os vectores.
while( a[index] == b[index] )
{
    // Verifica se alguma das strings terminou.
    // Se sim, sai do loop. Caso contrario, analisa o próximo carácter.
    if( a[index] == '\0' || b[index] == '\0' )
        break;
    ++index;
}

// Se ambos terminaram, as strings contidas são iguais.
if( a[index] == '\0' && b[index] == '\0' )
    return 0;
else
    return -1;
```

Comment: Obrigado Omni, gostei de ambas as opções, é bom ver que tem a função pronta, mas opto pela implementação do algoritmo inteiro, valeu.