# Ler uma string com quebra de linha

Tags: c, string, struct

Preciso comparar duas strings para saber se são iguais.

Uma delas está em um vetor de *struct* e foi lida com o *fgets*, portanto está com quebra de linha. A outra é informada pelo teclado.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma função para ler essa segunda *struct* com quebra de linha, para que eu possa compará-la a primeira.

Answer (score 1):

Podes retirar a quebra de linha na primeira string (numa copia se necessario)

```
fgets(exemplo, sizeof exemplo, stdin); // assume no errors
len = strlen(exemplo);
if ((len > 0) && (exemplo[len - 1] == '\n')) {
    exemplo[--len] = 0; // remove quebra de linha e actualiza len
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução, ao invés de alterar uma das `strings` e remover as quebras de linha, pode passar por implementar uma comparação sua.

Um exemplo dessa comparação seria (baseado ligeiramente nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/39656/8113)):

```
// Retorna 0 se as strings forem iguais, -1 se forem diferentes
int CompareStrings(char* a, char* b);

int CompareStrings(char* a, char* b)
{
    int indexA, indexB;
    for(indexA = 0, indexB = 0; indexA < strlen(a) || indexB < strlen(b); ++indexA, ++indexB)
    {
        if(a[indexA] == '\n')
        {
            if(++indexA >= strlen(a))
                indexA = strlen(a);
        }

        if(b[indexB] == '\n')
        {
            if(++indexB >= strlen(b))
                indexB = strlen(b);
        }

        if((a[indexA] == '\0' || b[indexB] == '\0') || (a[indexA] != b[indexB]))
            break;
    }

    // Se ambos terminaram, as strings contidas são iguais.
    if( a[indexA] == '\0' && b[indexB] == '\0' )
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/b1K6w9) com testes.

Answer (score -1):

Podes fazer `strlen(variavel sem \n)`, depois copias o final da *string* para a localizaçao do `\n` e depois disso podes comparar as strings.