# Como criar programa em C que pode usar parametros?

Tags: c

Estou estudando C, e agora tentando passar parâmetros.
Bom, embora eu esteja achando que tenha conseguido, esta dando erro quando tento usar aquela variável...

Explico, a char "argument_value"  que passo na linha de comando, pode ser impressa na tela sem o menor problema, mas se uso ela dentro de um IF, eh como se ela nao existisse...

Eu preciso comparar a char "argument_value" para tomar decisões no programa!

O que posso estar fazendo de errado?

```
int main (int argument_count, char *argument_value[]) {

            printf("\n");
            printf("\nargument_value[0]  : %s", argument_value[0]);
            printf("\nargument_value[1]  :   %s", argument_value[1]);
            printf("\nargument_value[2]  :   %s", argument_value[2]);

            printf("\n");
            if      (argument_value[1] == "detailed"){printf("\n detalllll");}
            else if (argument_value[1] == "hexa")    {printf("\n hexaaaaaa");}
            else if (argument_value[1] == "bits")    {printf("\n bitsssss");}
            else                                     {printf("\n none...");}



}
```

Este codigo sempre me retorna os parametros que passe na linha de comando, e "none..."

Comment: Para comparar strings em C, utilize a função [`strcmp`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strcmp.htm). Exemplo [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39651/comparar-duas-strings-em-c/39656#39656)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confome indicado nesta [resposta do SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39651/comparar-duas-strings-em-c/39656#39656):

Para comparar strings em C, utilize a função [`strcmp`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strcmp.htm).

Exemplo:

```
if (strcmp(argument_value[1], "detailed") == 0) {printf("\n detalllll");}
```

Comment: valeu pela objetividade! e exemplos! agente que esta comencando sabe bem como eh importante ter isso! brigadão!

Comment: De nada @RobervalSena山本! :)